# ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database on Rest call

Tags: java, sql-server

Hello i got a program that restores databases from .bak files and it works fine when there is no database with that name but when i try it when there already is an database with the same name i get this error

```
    Could not send response error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: StatementCallback; SQL [IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'utv_johan')
BEGIN
ALTER DATABASE utv_johan SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
drop database utv_johan;
END
]; ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database 'utv_johan'.
```

I am doing a new version of an old app and on the old one it works fine with the statement and all. and i use the same code for this but with a new React GUI. Anyone know how this error occurs and how to fix it? If you need more info feel free to ask! i saw someone here with same error when he were trying to take down his sql server. But i have done nothing with the database same calls as the old version.

Its seem as after some more testing that it sometimes works and throws no error at all.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your [`DEADLOCK_PRIORITY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-deadlock-priority-transact-sql) is equal to or less than another session and thus, you aren't able to `ROLLBACK` their transaction. You can explicitly set your priority and see if this resolves it.

```
USE [MASTER]
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY 10
ALTER DATABASE utv_johan SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
DROP DATABASE utv_johan;
```